# Rubygems is not using $GEM_PATH environment variable

Tags: rubygems, rvm

I'm using rvm gemsets on linux to work on a rails app with older version of rails and ruby.  Everything makes sense except rubygems is not seeing the correct path for ruby or the gems. To illustrate, I want to use ruby 1.8.7 and a gemset called smsx

```
➜  rails git:(master) ✗ rvm current
ruby-1.8.7-p371@smsx
```

as expected

```
➜  rails git:(master) ✗ echo $GEM_PATH
/home/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@smsx:/home/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global
```

however

```
➜  rails git:(master) ✗ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.25
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-02-06 patchlevel 385) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385
  ... more ...
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385
     - /home/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global
  ... more ...
```

So rubygems recognises that I'm using rvm, but thinks I'm using a different ruby and the default gemset.  It's like rubygems is ignoring the relevant environment variables completely.

Any suggestion on likely causes?

Edit:

Additional information as requested

```
➜  rails git:(master) ✗ echo $PATH
/home/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@smsx/bin:/home/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-  p371@global/bin:/home/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin:/home/matt/.rvm/bin:/home/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin:/home/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/bin:/home/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

➜  rails git:(master) ✗ which gem
gem () {
    typeset result
    (
        typeset rvmrc
    rvm_rvmrc_files=("/etc/rvmrc" "$HOME/.rvmrc") 
    if [[ -n "${rvm_prefix:-}" ]] && ! [[ "$HOME/.rvmrc" -ef "${rvm_prefix}/.rvmrc" ]]
    then
        rvm_rvmrc_files+=("${rvm_prefix}/.rvmrc") 
    fi
    for rvmrc in "${rvm_rvmrc_files[@]}"
    do
        [[ -s "${rvmrc}" ]] && source "${rvmrc}" || true
    done
    unset rvm_rvmrc_files
    command gem "$@"
) || result=$? 
hash -r
return ${result:-0}
```

}

I'm using oh-my-zsh.

Comment: Thanks for your question, info added to initial post.

Comment: I have none of the rc files you listed.  I have a project .rvmrc containing `rvm use 1.8.7@smsx`.  The only oh-my-zsh plugin I use is git, disabling this sadly did not help.

Comment: can you add `which -a gem`

Comment: Note I reinstalled RVM.  This has resolved the issue.  Thanks @mpapis for looking at this.